# How to properly annotate object variables that are part of primary key in Room entity?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am getting an error: "You must annotate primary keys with @NonNull. "name" is nullable."

I do not understand what the source of this error is as I am very clearly annotating my String variable "name" with @NonNull that is declared as part of the composite primary key. Am I setting up my composite primary key incorrectly?

```
@Entity(tableName = "ScavItems",
        primaryKeys = { "scavHuntID", "name" },
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(entity = ScavHunt.class,
                        parentColumns = "shID",
                        childColumns = "scavHuntID")
        })
public class ScavItem {
    @NonNull private int scavHuntID;
    @NonNull private String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "found")
    private boolean found;

    public ScavItem(int scavHuntID, String name){
        this.scavHuntID = scavHuntID;
        this.name = name;
        found = false;
    }

    public String getName(){ return this.name; }
    public boolean getFound(){ return this.found; }
    public int getScavHuntID(){ return this.scavHuntID; }
    public void setFound(boolean found){ this.found = found; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was importing the incorrect NonNull package.
This is the correct import:

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
```